# TikZ environment style options don't work inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, expl3, latex3, xparse

I want to use a TikZ environment inside an `\ExplSyntaxOn... \ExplSyntaxOff` block.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketikz}{ O{,} m }{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    padding/.append style={inner sep=2px},%
    node distance=2pt
]
    \node[draw] {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    
\maketikz[;]{Yes}
    
\end{document}
```

During the build process I get errors for the TikZ styles: `I do not know the key '/tikz/padding/.appendstyle', to which you passed 'innersep=2px...` and `I do not know the key '/tikz/nodedistance', to which you passed '2pt'...`.

Without `\ExplSyntaxOn` it builds without any errors.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\newcommand{\maketikz}[2][,]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    padding/.append style={inner sep=2px},%
    node distance=2pt
]
    \node[draw] {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
    
\maketikz[;]{Yes}
    
\end{document}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: in expl3 context spaces are ignored, and you must use `~`, e.g. `padding/.append~style={inner~sep=2px}`

Comment: Don't use `px`. Very likely it is not what you might think it to be.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ooohhh, this should have been so obvious, thanks alot!

Comment: @egreg it was just a typo of CSS muscle memory, thanks

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `ExplSyntax` is turnd `On` spaces are ignored and `~` needs to be used instead.

To quote the manual `interface3.pdf`:

> The `\ExplSyntaxOn` function switches to a category code regime in which spaces and
> new lines are ignored, and in which the colon (`:`) and underscore (`_`) are treated as “letters”, thus allowing access to the names of code functions and variables. Within this environment, `~` is used to input a space. The `\ExplSyntaxOff` reverts to the document category code regime.

Thus you need to use `~` instead of spaces to use the corrent key names.

This also means that you don't have to use `%` after the opening `{` or after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

The ones after `[` and `,` in the options that get passed to PGFKeys aren't necessary either, even without `\ExplSyntaxOn` because PGFKeys ignores the spaces from the get-go

I've added a bit text around your macro to show that they are no spaces included.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketikz}{ O{,} m }{ % ← space doesn't need to be %ed
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    padding/.append~style = {inner~sep = 2pt},
    node~distance         = 2pt ]
\node[draw, padding] {#2};
\end{tikzpicture} % ← space doesn't need to be %ed
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Foo\maketikz[;]{Yes}Bar
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]